# plz correct my validation code

Tags: javascript, css, html

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">

  function validate()
  {
 var product1 = document.getElementById("product").value;
var description1 = document.getElementById("description").value;
var category1 = document.getElementById("category").value;
var pricerange1 = document.getElementById("pricerange").value;
var city1 = document.getElementById("city").value;
var location1 = document.getElementById("location").value;
var name1 = document.getElementById("name").value;
var email1 = document.getElementById("email").value;
var mobile1 = document.getElementById("mobile").value;
    if(product1.length <= 0 || category1.length <= 0||description1.length <= 0||pricerange.length <= 0||city1.length <= 0||location1.length <= 0||name1.length <= 0||email1.length <= 0||mobile1.length <= 0)
    {
        if(product1.length <= 0)
            {
            document.getElementById('eproduct').innerHTML = "This field is mandatory";
            }
        if(description1.length <= 0)
            {
            document.getElementById('edescription').innerHTML = "This field is mandatory";
            }
            if(category1.length <= 0)
            {
            document.getElementById('ecategory').innerHTML = "This field is mandatory";
            }
            if(pricerange1.length <= 0)
            {
            document.getElementById('epricerange').innerHTML = "This field is mandatory";
            }
            if(city1.length <= 0)
            {
            document.getElementById('ecity').innerHTML = "This field is mandatory";
            }
            if(location1.length <= 0)
            {
            document.getElementById('elocation').innerHTML = "This field is mandatory";
            }
            if(name1.length <= 0)
            {
            document.getElementById('ename').innerHTML = "This field is mandatory";
            }
            if(email1.length <= 0)
            {
            document.getElementById('eemail').innerHTML = "This field is mandatory";
            }
            if(mobile1.length <= 0)
            {
            document.getElementById('emobile').innerHTML = "This field is mandatory";
            }
        return false;
        alert("Your form not registered");
    }
else
{return true;}
}

                  }
</script>
<style>
    .form{color: red; font-family: Calibri; font-size: 12px;}
    </style>
</head>
<body style="background-color:whitesmoke;">
  <form name="myform" action="" method="post" onsubmit="return validate();">

  <font size="20px" color="green" style="font-family:Comic Sans MS;">Submit your ad.......</font></br></br>
  <table>
  <tr>
 <td> U want to buy</td>
 <td>:</td>
 <td><input type="text" name="product" id="product" onsubmit="validate();"> <span id="eproduct" class="form"></span></td>
  </tr>


  <tr>
  <td>Category</td>
  <td>:</td>
  <td><select id="category">
              <option value="1">Books</option>  
               <option value="2">Computers & Peripherals</option>
                <option value="3">Electronics</option>
                 <option value="4">Mobiles</option>
                  <option value="5">Paints</option>
                   <option value="6">Woods</option>
                    <option value="7">Tyres</option>
            </select>   <span id="ecategory" class="form"></span></td>
    </tr>       
 <tr>
<td> Description</td>
<td>:</td>
<td><textarea name="description" id="description"></textarea> <span id="edescription" class="form"></span></td></tr>
 <tr> 
 <td>Price Range</td>
 <td>:</td>
 <td><input type="text" name="pricerange" id="pricerange"><span  id="epricerange" class="form"></span></td>
 </tr>
 <tr>

 <td> City</td>
 <td>:</td>
 <td><input type="text" name="city" id="city" value="In which u want to buy"><span id="ecity" class="form"></span></td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
 <td> Your Location</td>
 <td>:</td>
 <td colspan="2"><textarea  name="location" id="location">Your address</textarea><span id="elocation" class="form"></span></td></tr>
 <tr>
  <td>Name</td>
  <td>:</td>
  <td><input type="text" name="name" value="your name" id="name"><span id="ename" class="form"></span></td></tr>

  <tr>
  <td>Email</td>
  <td>:</td>
  <td><input type="text" name="email" value="Enter your email id.." id="email"><span id="eemail" class="form"></span></td></tr>
 <tr>
<td> Mobile</td>
<td>:</td>
<td><input type="text" name="mobile" value="eg.+91-**********" id="mobile"><span id="emobile" class="form"></span></td></tr>

 <tr> 
 <td><input type="Submit" value="Submit" id="submit"></td></tr>
 </table>
  </form>
  </body>
  </html>
```

Comment: Can you please give details about things going wrong, and wat do u expect from it?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because "Correct my code" questions without knowing what actually goes wrong won't benefit the community. Please edit your question and specify what goes wrong where. Thank you!

Comment: Probably a suggestion anyway, but those input fields you're better off with placeholder attribute than the value attribute (otherwise you're always going to get values in them... albeit, that's probably faster for you to submit the form, but you're obviously not doing much validation if the values are already there, you're just waiting for them to delete those values to trigger that on submit).

Your alert box is also after the return false statement, that's never going to show either :)

Comment: We are not your employees here!

Comment: You should probably post this to programmers se.